# Exception while calling Parser method outside main class

Tags: java, exception, servlets, model, nlp

In my application I have a method which I cant execute without main method. It only runs inside the main method. When I call that method inside my servlet class. It show an exception

> 1. My class with Main Method

```
    package com.books.servlet;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import opennlp.tools.cmdline.parser.ParserTool;
import opennlp.tools.parser.Parse;
import opennlp.tools.parser.Parser;
import opennlp.tools.parser.ParserFactory;
import opennlp.tools.parser.ParserModel;

public class ParserTest {

    // download

    public void download(String url, File destination) throws IOException, Exception {
        URL website = new URL(url);
        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
        fos.close();
        rbc.close();

    }

    public static Set<String> nounPhrases = new HashSet<>();

    private static String line = "The Moon is a barren, rocky world ";

    public void getNounPhrases(Parse p) {
        if (p.getType().equals("NN") || p.getType().equals("NNS") || p.getType().equals("NNP")
                || p.getType().equals("NNPS")) {
            nounPhrases.add(p.getCoveredText());
        }

        for (Parse child : p.getChildren()) {
            getNounPhrases(child);
        }
    }

    public void parserAction() throws Exception {
        // InputStream is = new FileInputStream("en-parser-chunking.bin");
        File modelFile = new File("en-parser-chunking.bin");

        if (!modelFile.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Downloading model.");
            download("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B4uQtYVPbChrY2ZIWmpRQ1FSVVk", modelFile);

        }
        ParserModel model = new ParserModel(modelFile);
        Parser parser = ParserFactory.create(model);
        Parse topParses[] = ParserTool.parseLine(line, parser, 1);
        for (Parse p : topParses) {
            // p.show();
            getNounPhrases(p);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new ParserTest().parserAction();
        System.out.println("List of Noun Parse : " + nounPhrases);

    }
}
```

It gives me below output

> List of Noun Parse : [barren,, world, Moon]

Then I commented the main method and. Called the ParserAction() method in my servlet class

```
if (name.equals("bkDescription")) {

                    bookDes = value;

                    try {

                        new ParserTest().parserAction(); 

                        System.out.println("Nouns Are"+ParserTest.nounPhrases);

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
```

It gives me the below exceptions

[image: EXception]

And below error in my Browser

[image: Error in browser]

Why is this happening ? I can run this with main method. But when I remove main method and called in my servlet. it gives an exception. Is there any way to fix this issue ?

NOTE - I have read below instructions in OpenNLP documentation , but I have no clear idea about it. Please help me to fix his issue.

> Unlike the other components to instantiate the Parser a factory method
>   should be used instead of creating the Parser via the new operator.
>   The parser model is either trained for the chunking parser or the tree
>   insert parser the parser implementation must be chosen correctly. The
>   factory method will read a type parameter from the model and create an
>   instance of the corresponding parser implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Either create an object of ParserTest class or remove new keyword in this line `new ParserTest().parserAction();`